# How can i change the Birthday in a Google GMail Contact?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-contacts-api

I change to change the properties of my Gmail Contact from a webform in ASP.NET ?
I can change the most of properties but i cant change the birthday. Here is my code :

```
    Dim contact As Contact = cr.Retrieve(Of Contact)(contactURL)
    contact.Name.FullName = m.Prenom & " " & m.Nom
    contact.Name.FamilyName = m.Nom
    contact.Name.GivenName = m.Prenom
    contact.PrimaryEmail.Address = m.AdresseMail

    Dim adr As StructuredPostalAddress = contact.PostalAddresses(0)
    adr.Primary = True
    adr.Street = m.Adresse
    adr.Postcode = m.CodePostal
    adr.City = m.Ville
    adr.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome

    Dim d As New Date
    d = CDate(m.DateNaissance)
    contact.ContactEntry.Birthday = d.Year & "-" & d.Month & "-" & d.Day

    Try
    Dim updatedContact As Contact = cr.Update(contact)

    Catch e As GDataVersionConflictException
       ' Do Something
    Finally
       'do Something
    End Try
```

i got an error that :

```
    [WebException: Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (400) Demande incorrecte.]
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6542104
    Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() +136

    [GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxx/full/xxxxxxx]
       Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() +291
       Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter) +653
       Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute() +34
       Google.GData.Client.Service.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data) +430
    Google.GData.Client.FeedRequest`1.Update(Y entry) +417
       FlbMembres.CtlMajGmail.MajGmail() in C:\Mes Sites Web\FLBMembres\FlbWeb\ControlesUser\CtlMajGmail.ascx.vb:187
       FlbMembres.CtlMajGmail.btnMaj_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Mes Sites Web\FLBMembres\FlbWeb\ControlesUser\CtlMajGmail.ascx.vb:200
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628114
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
                                                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: I don't speak much French but the error message basically states that you have a malformed request somewhere. Recheck the format you are using for the birth date. Pheraps your day or month are lacking a leading zero? The format has to be yyyy-MM-dd, so a date like `1983-12-1` would be invalid (but `1983-12-01` would be correct).

Comment: You're right... Its because my birthday was 1970-2-1 and not 1970-02-01. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing your date like this:

```
Dim d As New Date
d = CDate(m.DateNaissance)
contact.ContactEntry.Birthday = d.Year & "-" & d.Month & "-" & d.Day
```

The `Day` and `Month` properties of the Date type are numeric. That means that if either one is less than 10, you get a one digit month or one digit day. For example, January first of 2014 would become `2014-1-1`.

But Google expects dates to be formatted like `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Just check the length of the day and month, and make sure they have a leading zero if needed.

Since you are using .NET, the `DateTime` struct has a `ToString` method that takes a format string. You could replace your code with:

```
Dim d As New Date
d = CDate(m.DateNaissance)
contact.ContactEntry.Birthday = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

... And you would get a string in the format you need, with less concatenations. *Bonne chance!*